# Git filter-branch not rewriting all history

Tags: git, git-svn, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to re-write a repo's history using:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = jacks* ]]
        then
            cn="Jack Slingerland"
            cm="jacks@teamddm.com"
            an="Jack Slingerland"
            am="jacks@teamddm.com"

        fi

        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = jacks* ]]
        then
            cn="Jack Slingerland"
            cm="jacks@teamddm.com"
            an="Jack Slingerland"
            am="jacks@teamddm.com"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"'
 -- --all
```

The command runs fine, and rewrites the author as specified.  The problem is that it seems to miss some entries in the history.  I think it's happening when changes made in a branch were merged in, but I'm not sure.

Note: This is an SVN repository that was imported into Git using Git+SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your conditionals are checking what you want.  Shouldn't:

```
if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = jacks* ]]
```

be

```
if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" =~ "jacks.*" ]]
```

Note: this will only work in Bash 3.0 or higher. Otherwise I think you'll need to use `grep` or `sed` external commands as part of your conditional checks.

Also, I think you will only want to change the commiter when the commiter's email isn't Jack's and vice versa for the author.  So make sure you take out your `an` and `am` assignments in your comitter email check and make the similar fix to your author email check.

Comment: I end up getting a syntax error (bash 3.2):
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 335: syntax error near `~='

/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 335: `if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" ~= "jonw.*" ]]'
env filter failed:

Comment: Swapping the order of the '~' and '=' fixed the syntax error.

Comment: @JackSlingerland did the change help?